# How to optimise foreach loop in entity framework in dot net core c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, foreach, entity-framework-core

I need to optimised this code, it takes half an hour more time to display data. I used this code: -

```
public IEnumerable<ParcelList> GetAll()
{
   List<ParcelList> allData = new List<ParcelList>();
   List<Parcel> allparcels = _context.Parcela.OrderByDescending(o => o.id).ToList();// Containing records 4,64,872 having 76 columns fields
   foreach (Parcel item in allparcels)
   {
      ParcelList p = new ParcelList();
      p.parcel = new ParcelName();
      p.parcel.col1name = "";
      p.parcel.col2name = "";
      p.parcel.col3name = "";
      p.parcel.col1 = item.col1;
      p.parcel.col2 = item.col2;
      p.parcel.col3 = item.col3;
      p.parcel.col4 = item.col4;
      p.parcel.col5 = item.col5;
      try
      {
         p.parcel.CountryName = _context.Concelho
            .Where(w => Convert.ToInt64(w.col1) == Convert.ToInt64(item.col1))
            .Select(s => s.col1name)
            .FirstOrDefault();

         p.parcel.DistrictName = _context.Distrito
            .Where(w => Convert.ToInt64(w.col2) == Convert.ToInt64(item.col2))
            .Select(s => s.col2name)
            .FirstOrDefault();

         p.parcel.ParishName = _context.Freguesia
            .Where(w => Convert.ToInt64(w.col3) == Convert.ToInt64(item.col3))
            .Select(s => s.col3name)
            .FirstOrDefault();

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
         // I should never ever ever swallow exceptions
         // I should never ever ever swallow exceptions
         // I should never ever ever swallow exceptions
      }

      p.Explorer = _context.Explorer.AsNoTracking()
         .Where(w => w.pid == item.id)
         .Where(w1 => w1.VERSAO == item.VERSAO)
         .ToList()
         .ToArray();

      p.Property = _context.Property.AsNoTracking()
         .Where(w => w.pid == item.id)
         .Where(w1 => w1.VERSAO == item.VERSAO)
         .ToList()
         .ToArray();
      allData.Add(p);
   }
   return allData;
}
```

In this, the Table contains records 4,64,872 having 76 columns fields.
Please help!!

Comment: The selects in the the loop are killers. I personally would create a View which reperesents exactly what I want to display and map that to a new class to get the fastest result.

Comment: @Turo .. please send the sample code

Comment: In any case don’t call `ToList()` *and* `ToArray()`. If you want an array, just the last one. If a list, then the first one. Both is adding to the complexity.

Comment: The problem is you are calling 5 queries 464,872 times. This could likely be done in one query, however without seeing your structure its hard to help

Comment: @TheGeneral - the structure is simply a class. How can I do it in one query? please show some sample code

Comment: The structure that was meant is the database structure. This whole method can possibly be transformed into a single database query (through LINQ or a view), where the database does all the matching. You do have foreign keys set up, I hope? And correct data types, so you don't need to Convert.ToInt64 all IDs

Comment: I will suggest extracting the CountryName/DistrictName/ParishName queries within the forloop out and simply load and cache them in some form of lookup table. This is because these are commonly accessed and mostly static lookup key value pairs. You can in fact load CountryName/DistrictName/ParishName into dictionaries first once outside the loop and then fetch by the w.col keys.